# removing duplicate cycles of directed graph from a list in scala

Tags: scala, graph, cycle

I have collection of lists shown below.

```
List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)
List(4, 0, 1, 3, 4)
List(4, 0, 2, 3, 4)
List(4, 3, 2, 3, 4)
List(4, 3, 4, 3, 4)
List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0)
List(0, 1, 3, 4, 0)
List(0, 2, 3, 4, 0)
List(1, 2, 4, 0, 1)
List(1, 3, 4, 0, 1)
List(3, 4, 0, 1, 3)
List(3, 4, 0, 2, 3)
List(3, 2, 3, 2, 3)
List(3, 4, 3, 2, 3)
List(3, 2, 3, 4, 3)
List(3, 4, 3, 4, 3)
List(2, 3, 4, 0, 2)
List(2, 4, 0, 1, 2)
List(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
List(2, 3, 4, 3, 2)
```

These lists are the individual cycles in a directed graph with cycle length of 4. I want to filter out the number of unique path from the given lists which does not have any smaller path in between. For example - List(4,0,1,2,4) and List(0,1,2,4,0) forms the same cycle. Another example - List(2,3,2,3,2) iterates over 2 and 3 only and does not form the cycle length 4.

From this collection we can say that List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0) List(0, 1, 3, 4, 0) List(0, 2, 3, 4, 0) are the unique paths and total number would be 3.
List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0) and List(4,0,1,2,4) is the same cycle so we take one of them.

I tried to use filter but unable to find any logic to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should work:

```
val input = List(List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4),List(4, 0, 1, 3, 4) ,List(4, 0, 2, 3, 4) ,List(4, 3, 2, 3, 4) ,List(4, 3, 4, 3, 4) ,
    List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0) ,List(0, 1, 3, 4, 0) ,List(0, 2, 3, 4, 0) ,List(1, 2, 4, 0, 1) ,List(1, 3, 4, 0, 1) ,List(3, 4, 0, 1, 3) ,
    List(3, 4, 0, 2, 3) ,List(3, 2, 3, 2, 3) ,List(3, 4, 3, 2, 3) ,List(3, 2, 3, 4, 3) ,List(3, 4, 3, 4, 3) ,
    List(2, 3, 4, 0, 2) ,List(2, 4, 0, 1, 2) ,List(2, 3, 2, 3, 2), List(2, 3, 4, 3, 2))

  var uniquePaths: mutable.Set[List[Int]] = collection.mutable.Set[List[Int]]()
  var indexes: ListBuffer[Int] = mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()

  input.zipWithIndex.foreach{x =>
    val (list, index) = (x._1, x._2)
      if(list.head==list.last) {
        val list1 = rotateArray(list.tail)
        if (list1.toSet.size == 4) {
          if(!uniquePaths.contains(list1))
            indexes.append(index)
          uniquePaths.add(list1)
        }
      }
  }

  indexes foreach{x => println(input(x))}

  def rotateArray(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
    xs.splitAt(xs.indexOf(xs.min)) match {case (x, y) => List(y, x).flatten}
```

Comment: Thanks mukesh, I tried your code. I have the list in RDD format and I am getting this error "value last is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId]]"

Comment: I converted my rdd to normal list type and it solved the problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Sam Since `list.head == list.last` is a property that always holds, the code is equivalent to `input.foreach{list => uniquePaths.add(list.tail.sorted)}`, which is obviously nonsense, because it erases the differences between all cycles that go through the same vertices. The fact that in your tiny example `0,1,2,4`, `0,1,3,4` and `0,2,3,4` happen to appear "sorted" does not make this code correct.

Comment: @Mukeshprajapati Both branches of the `if-else` contain the same statement, therefore the `if-else` is superfluous and can be removed. Please don't use `.map` for side-effects (mutating the list), use `.foreach` instead. Also, `drop(1)` on `List` is the same as `.tail`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I checked list.head==list.tail just to be sure that list is cyclic. It can be removed if list is sure to be cyclic in nature.

Comment: @Mukeshprajapati still, `if(...) statement else statement` with the same `statement` in both branches is redundant. Could you please simplify it away? ...and also remove that `map`, it looks weird. It should be something like `if (list1.toSet.size == 4) { uniquePaths.add(list1) }` instead the entire `if-else`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I followed your suggestion removed the redundant code. In the uniquePaths everytime I am getting a extra empty list, do not know why, everything else is fine.

Comment: while initializing the uniquePaths a empty list is automatically added there, thats why in the end also i am getting one extra empty list.

Comment: The syntax got better, but it's still erasing the structure of the cycle by sorting...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yeah... We can avoid it by storing index separately.

Comment: How is storing the *index of the cycle* supposed to restore the *order of the vertices within each cycle* once you've sorted the vertices?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "indexes" array will store the index of the "input" array. "uniquePaths" array will only be used to see if path is unique or not. At the end, we are seeing "input" array index.

Comment: This index doesn't matter, and it doesn't fix the code. Try it out with `val input = List(
  List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4),
  List(4, 0, 2, 1, 4),
  List(4, 1, 0, 2, 4),
  List(4, 1, 2, 0, 4),
  List(4, 2, 0, 1, 4),
  List(4, 2, 1, 0, 4)
)`. The result will contain only *one* cycle, even though all six cycles in the input are obviously different.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yeah... I got your point. In the question it is mentioned that  List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0) and List(4,0,1,2,4) is the same cycle and we can take one of them. So, currently code will take first list as result.

Comment: It's mentioned that `[0, 1, 2, 4, 0]` and `[4, 0, 1, 2, 4]` are the same, because *they are the same*. But `[4, 0, 1, 2, 4]` and `[4, 0, 2, 1, 4]` are *not* the same (draw it on a piece of paper, if you want...), but they are still collapsed to just one entry by your code.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have edited answer. It gives correct answer now.

Comment: It's kind-of getting better... It doesn't give correct answer, because it now can no longer see that `[0, 1, 2, 4, 0]` and `[4, 0, 1, 2, 4]` are the same. You forgot the `.tail`/`.drop(1)`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

...freehand red cycles to the rescue.

Here are two *different* cycles *on the same four vertices*, which shows  that **sorting is insufficient**:

[image]

The sketch assumes that all the points are vertices of a fully connected graph (edges omitted), and is supposed to show that the cycles `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0]` and `[0, 2, 1, 3, 0]` are not the same, despite the fact that if you sort the sets, you obtain `[0, 1, 2, 3]` in both cases.

Here is what might work instead:

1. Throw away all the paths which go through the same vertex more than once by filtering out all the paths that do not consist of four distinct elements.
2. **Rotate** the path representation into canonical form (e.g. starting at the vertex with minimum position).
3. Compute the set of canonical representations, retaining only the unique paths.

Here is what the implementation might look like:

```
def canonicalize(cycle: List[Int]) = {
  val t = cycle.tail
  val (b, a) = t.splitAt(t.zipWithIndex.minBy(_._1)._2)
  val ab = (a ++ b)
  ab :+ (ab.head)
}

val cycles = List(
  List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4),
  List(4, 0, 1, 3, 4),
  List(4, 0, 2, 3, 4),
  List(4, 3, 2, 3, 4),
  List(4, 3, 4, 3, 4),
  List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0),
  List(0, 1, 3, 4, 0),
  List(0, 2, 3, 4, 0),
  List(1, 2, 4, 0, 1),
  List(1, 3, 4, 0, 1),
  List(3, 4, 0, 1, 3),
  List(3, 4, 0, 2, 3),
  List(3, 2, 3, 2, 3),
  List(3, 4, 3, 2, 3),
  List(3, 2, 3, 4, 3),
  List(3, 4, 3, 4, 3),
  List(2, 3, 4, 0, 2),
  List(2, 4, 0, 1, 2),
  List(2, 3, 2, 3, 2),
  List(2, 3, 4, 3, 2)
)

val unique = cycles.filter(_.toSet.size == 4).map(canonicalize).toSet

unique foreach println
```

Output:

```
List(0, 1, 2, 4, 0)
List(0, 1, 3, 4, 0)
List(0, 2, 3, 4, 0)
```

Line-by-line example of what `canonicalize` does:

1. `tail` removes the duplicate vertex: `[2, 1, 0, 4, 2] -> [1, 0, 4, 2]`
2. `splitAt` finds the minimum vertex and cuts the list: `[1, 0, 4, 2] -> ([1], [0, 4, 2])`
3. `a ++ b` rebuilds the rotated list: `[0, 4, 2, 1]`
4. `:+` appends the minimum vertex to the end: `[0, 4, 2, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop the last element from the list (it's redundant)
2. Scroll the lists to start from the smallest ID
3. Sort loops by the length shortest first
4. You can use lexical matching now (if loop[i] contains any loop[0..i-1] -> drop it)

Comment: Thanks bobah, I got your logic but am pretty new with scala syntax. Can you explain a bit more with code. It will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Sam - then I would write it in a language that you are not new with and ask a question "help converting XXX to Scala", cause you have two problems, not one :-)

Comment: :) . I can get it in python or java.

Comment: @Sam I think one can still safely assume that most Scala programmers can at least read/understand Java code, so maybe you could add a proposal how you would want to solve it in Java, and then ask how this can be done in Scala.